# How bosh set the vm network in vsphere environment?

Tags: cloud-foundry, cf-bosh

I am learning the bosh and cloudfoundry , I am curiosity about the vm network setting in the vsphere.

How the bosh setup the network (ip, gateway) for the vm in the vsphere. i know the bosh will fire a bosh-agent/nats-agent in the target vm to change the value, but how it first connect to the agent ?

because i am not familiar with go, ruby , so cannot figure out the code .

Answer (score 0):

https://bosh.io/docs/vsphere-cpi.html explains interactions with VSphere, and related bosh configuration.

> How the bosh setup the network (ip, gateway) for the vm in the vsphere.

Are you looking to understand how to configure bosh, or how the CPI interacts with vsphere?

The docs above answer the first part. As for how bosh CPI operates under the cover is uses the vsphere/SDK APIS documented here, https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk41pubs/ApiReference/index-methods.html